# With Mercurial: How to record different machines source code changes happened on

Tags: mercurial, repository

I use Mercurial on 2 different computers changing the same repository. If I want to keep tabs on which changes have happened on which machine, how should I record this?

I came up with the idea of using **different user names** on the two machines (`[ui] -->
username` variable in the hg config file), but does a more appropriate mechanism/variable exists for this?

Comment: This looks like a good idea; user names are exactly to identify the commiter, here the computer. The alternative would be to work on different branches on each computer and merge in default often. However, this is more error-prone.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. This kind of answers my question.Do you want to make the comment into an answer, please?

Comment: Thanks for the offer! Comment was because you already offered a perfectly good answer, but you had me at please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a couple of years, you've been able to expand shell variables inside `.hg/hgrc` files.

So I just do something like this in my `.bash_profile`:

> export HGUSER=$(hostname)

Then inside `.hg/hgrc`:

> username=${HGUSER}

The **BIG ADVANTAGE** of this technique is that now you can put the **EXACT SAME** `.hg/hgrc` on **ALL** the machines.  The same is true of `.bash_profile`: it can be the same on all machines.  This helps a lot when you're automating machine configurations!

Note: the `HGUSER` environment variable is an old way of telling Mercurial your username, so, technically, setting `HGUSER` in `.bash_profile` ought to solve the problem on its own, but I believe its use is deprecated/discouraged, and I recommend defining `username` in `.hg/hgrc` explicitly, as I've shown above.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a good idea; user names are exactly to identify the *committer*, here the computer. The alternative would be to work on different branches on each computer and merge in default often. However, the latter is more error-prone.